# onClick logic based on image displayed

Tags: java, android

How do you change what onClick is doing based on the image that is displayed when clicked? I have an ImageView that changes the image to one of a set randomly in an onClick method. I would like this to set a score based on the image when clicked, and am unsure of how to accomplish this. I'm currently updating the score when the image changes as part of the prototype, but for actual game play this won't work. Not looking for the answer, so much as being pointed in the right direction. My first thought was to pull the image name as a string and compare that, but doing that every time an image is clicked seems inefficient. I can post the onClick method for the ImageView if requested, but it's not really relevant. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I'm not having any particular problem. I'm just wrong on my approach. What I have updates the score when the image changes, and I want to complete this based on the image that is being clicked. Should this be done with string comparison, or is there a better way to complete this? I haven't been able to find anything related to this so far.

```
final ImageView block1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin1);
    block1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.apptour);
            final Random rand = new Random();
            final int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
            final int resID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);

            TextView id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID);

            block1.setImageResource(resID);

            if (rndInt == 0 || rndInt == 1) {
                score++;
                id.setText("Score: " + score);
            } else if (rndInt == 2) {
                score += 5;
                id.setText("Score: " + score);
            } else {
                id.setText("Game Over");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Not looking for the answer" seems to contradict the idea of this page (this is an Q&A page). Your question may get flagged as "too broad". Better show some code you have tried so far, and point out where your problem is. If your problem is how to get started, you should better look for some tutorials instead.

Comment: Updated question for clarity.

Comment: "Should this be done with string comparison, or is there a better way to complete this?" -- try it with string comparison first. If you get that to work, look to optimize it after that. One thing you may want to look into after you get it working is hash maps.